# Static files are not loading inside html Apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am facing a strange issue, static files are loading inside html tags but they are loading fine directory. Css, Js, Images etc all are loading fine when access them directly but not loading when they inside html. PHP version is 5.6. I have no access to SSH only to cPanel as it is the shared hosting. Please help me solve this issue, Thanks.

**my .htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I also don't know which permission I have to ask to my host if it's on.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` these 2 should be above the firsr rule

Comment: @nogad I put them above `RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]` and server gave `Internal Server Error`

Comment: guys no one can help in this issue?

Comment: it really belongs on serverfult not here